# Duplicate Entry on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question after I insert table 
always getting error #1062 - Duplicate entry '12196076' for key 'PRIMARY'
but i don't insert this number before '12196076' why i always getting this error please explain me  ???

```
INSERT INTO `mahasiswa` (`NPM`, `Nama`, `Alamat`) VALUES ('12196076', 'Alya', 'Bogor'), ('11196779', 'Didi', 'Jakarta'), ('12196324', 'Tata', 'Depok'), ('10196839', 'Vinka', 'Bekasi'), ('10196999', 'Sely', 'Jakarta')
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: So, what do you get when you execute `SELECT * FROM mahasiswa WHERE NPM = '12196076' ` ? I suspect you have already inserted that value into the table.

Comment: :D thanks yeah looks like i have insert that npm :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe your query tries inserting two rows with the primary key column set to value 12196076.

try to hand / manually edit your SQL query / file to fix the problem. ( commenting out the duplicate )

maybe you can drop the primary key to avoid the error, then populate it with your current query and after that you proceed with another CREATE TABLE with a SELECT DISTINCT on the results.